# Pass generic type parameter to class expression

Tags: typescript

We have a class that is defined like this
`const A = class<T> {a: T}`
Goal is to describe a type of instance of this class with parameter `string`
Currently what I have is 
`const instanceType: InstanceType<typeof A>`

But I don't know how to pass type parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to ask why you don't just do things "the normal way".  That's your business!

---

I think this is one of those edge cases of the language where the lack of [generic values](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) or other [higher order types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453) bites you.  When you define a class "normally":

```
class B<T> { b!: T }
```

TypeScript creates a new named generic *type* `B<T>` for the instances, and a new named non-generic *value* `B` for the constructor, (whose type is a generic constructor function), sort of like the following:

```
type B<T> = {b: T};
declare const B: new<T>()=>B<T>;
```

So in this case if you want to refer to the instance type instantiated with `T` set to `string`, it's fine:

```
type InstanceOfBString = B<string>; // okay
```

But the way you did it creates a named *value*, but not a named type:

```
const A = class <T> { a!: T };
```

So now you have no type named `A` to use:

```
type InstanceOfAString = A<string>; // error, cannot find name A
```

Since the value `A` is not generic (as there are no generic values), you can't write `(typeof A)<T>` either.

Worse, you can't currently use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to inspect the type of `A` to plug in generic parameters.  This is a [design limitation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22617) of TS as of 3.3.  It's basically the lack of higher-order type support that is getting in our way.  There are some [possible changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) which might address this, but they are not in the language yet.

If we can't do it purely at the type level, we can do it with runtime effects:

```
const instanceOfAString = new A<string>(); 
type InstanceOfAString = typeof instanceOfAString;
```

If you don't want to actually call your constructor just to get a type out, you can play around with control flow to prevent it:

```
if (false) {
  // never called
  var instanceOfAString = new A<string>(); 
}
type InstanceOfAString = typeof instanceOfAString;
```

The constructor is never actually called at runtime, but the type system still determines a type for `instanceOfAString` that you can grab onto.  Yes, it's not completely invisible from the runtime... it appears in the emitted JavaScript, even though it essentially does nothing.  It's a workaround.

There was [an old proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606) to let you do something like `type InstanceOfAString = typeof (new A<string>())`, without invoking anything at runtime, but that is also not supported. So this is the closest I can get. ‍

---

Another way to go is to create the type `A` yourself, at the cost of some code duplication:

```
const A = class <T> { a!: T };
type A<T> = { a: T };
```

And now you can use it "as normal":

```
type InstanceOfAString = A<string>;
```

But of course if `A` has lots of properties you will essentially be listing them out twice.

---

Anyway, hope one of those ideas helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for response, your comment explains a lot.

I decided to use class expressions to organize actions in angular+ngrx application
Like:
`const LoginActions = {
  Login: class extends Action {},
  Logout: class extends Action {},
}`
Could you please advise other method to group actions ?